# Serializing object ready to send over TCPClient Stream

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I've got a server and client set up using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`.

I want to send an object to my server application for processing.

I've discovered the `using System.Runtime.Serialization` and the following [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx), but I didn't want to faff around to find that I'm doing it in long winded way.

The question: What is the best way to process and send an object over the TCP stream?

Sending and receiving.

**Here's an example of my object:**

```
// Create a new house to send
house newHouse = new house();

// Set variables
newHouse.street = "Mill Lane";
newHouse.postcode = "LO1 BT5";
newHouse.house_number = 11;
newHouse.house_id = 1;
newHouse.house_town = "London";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a class `House` (available on both sides of your connection) looking like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class House
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

You can serialize the class into a `MemoryStream`. You can then use in your `TcpClient` connection like this:

```
// Create a new house to send house and set values.
var newHouse = new House
    {
        Street = "Mill Lane", 
        ZipCode = "LO1 BT5", 
        Number = 11, 
        Id = 1, 
        Town = "London"
    };  

var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));
var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
if (networkStream.CanWrite)
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(networkStream, newHouse);
}
```

Of course you have to do a little more investigation to make the program running without exception. (e.g. Check `memoryStream.Length` not to be greater than an int, a.s.o.), but I hope I gave you the right suggestions to help you on your way ;-)

Comment: You can directly serialize to tcpClient's stream.

Comment: @L.B: Thanks for your tip, I changed the sample in that way!

Answer (score 4):

First create a empty ServerApplication and ClientApplication as Console Application to simplify the example.

*Then, put the definition for the serializable object into a separate assembly and then add a reference to the shared assembly to each project (server and client). Is necesary share the same object, not just an identical class copy.*

**To Generate DLL** >
Right clic in **Solution 'ServerApplication'** in the Solution Explorer > Add New Project... -> select Class Library
(e.g. name this project **MySharedHouse**)
Rename the default Class1 to House and complete it

```
[Serializable]
public class House
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Right clic in MySharedHouse and Build.

Now the dll is build and we need to add it in Server Project and Client Project.
Right clic in ServerApplication > Add Reference > Browse and find the dll, for this example

> Projects\ServerApplication\MySharedHouse\bin\Debug\MySharedHouse.dll

Repeat the process in ClientApplication using the same dll (same path).

Now you can use instances of House class in ServerApplication and ClientApplication as a single object, simply adding the sentence **"using MySharedHouse"** at the top.

**SERVER CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;
using MySharedHouse;

namespace ServerApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageServer s = new MessageServer(515);
            s.Start();
        }
    }

    public class MessageServer
    {
        private int _port;
        private TcpListener _tcpListener;
        private bool _running;
        private TcpClient connectedTcpClient;
        private BinaryFormatter _bFormatter;
        private Thread _connectionThread;

        public MessageServer(int port)
        {
            this._port = port;
            this._tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
            this._bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (!_running)
            {
                this._tcpListener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection... ");
                this._running = true;
                this._connectionThread = new Thread
                    (new ThreadStart(ListenForClientConnections));
                this._connectionThread.Start();
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (this._running)
            {
                this._tcpListener.Stop();
                this._running = false;
            }
        }

        private void ListenForClientConnections()
        {
            while (this._running)
            {
                this.connectedTcpClient = this._tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                House house = new House();
                house.Street = "Evergreen Terrace";
                house.ZipCode = "71474";
                house.Number = 742;
                house.Id = 34527;
                house.Town = "Springfield";
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), house);
                Console.WriteLine("send House!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Threading;
using MySharedHouse;

namespace ClientApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MessageClient client = new MessageClient(515);
            client.StartListening();
        }
    }

    public class MessageClient
    {
        private int _port;
        private TcpClient _tcpClient;
        private BinaryFormatter _bFormatter;
        private Thread _listenThread;
        private bool _running;
        private House house;

        public MessageClient(int port)
        {
            this._port = port;
            this._tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);
            this._bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            this._running = false;
        }

        public void StartListening()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (!_running)
                {
                    this._running = true;
                    this._listenThread = new Thread
                        (new ThreadStart(ListenForMessage));
                    this._listenThread.Start();
                }
                else
                {
                    this._running = true;
                    this._listenThread = new Thread
                        (new ThreadStart(ListenForMessage));
                    this._listenThread.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        private void ListenForMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading...");
            try
            {
                while (this._running)
                {
                    this.house = (House)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                    Console.WriteLine(this.house.Street);
                    Console.WriteLine(this.house.ZipCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(this.house.Number);
                    Console.WriteLine(this.house.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(this.house.Town);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wooala! the first house to be sent over TCP/IP

Answer (score 2):

Your answer implies the following object (it is common practice to name classes using [PascalCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)):

```
[Serializable]
class House:ISerializable
{
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string PostalCode {get; set;}
    public int HouseNumber {get; set;}
    public int HouseID {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    public House() { }
    protected House(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
        Street = (string)info.GetValue("Street ", typeof(string));
        PostalCode = (string)info.GetValue("PostalCode", typeof(string));
        HouseNumber = (int)info.GetValue("HouseNumber", typeof(int));
        HouseID = (int)info.GetValue("HouseID", typeof(int));
        City = (string)info.GetValue("City", typeof(string));
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, 
        Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) 
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
        info.AddValue("Street ", Street);
        info.AddValue("PostalCode", PostalCode);
        info.AddValue("HouseNumber", HouseNumber);
        info.AddValue("HouseID", HouseID );
        info.AddValue("City", City);
    }
}
```

Now you can serialize your objects:

```
void Send(Stream stream)
{
    BinaryFormatter binaryFmt = new BinaryFormatter();
    House h = new House()
    {
        Street = "Mill Lane",
        PostalCode = "LO1 BT5",
        HouseNumber = 11,
        HouseID = 1,
        City = "London"
    };

    binaryFmt.Serialize(stream, h);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply decorate your `House` class with the `[Serializable]` attribute. (You do not need to define all the other stuff as posted in the other answer)

You can then send this object on the wire by serializing it using the `BinaryFormatter` class.

Have you considered setting up a WCF service instead of using TcpListener and TcpClient ? Makes life a lot easier.

For instance you could define a service that returned a house

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    House GetHouse(int houseId);
}
```

See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx) real world example.

Answer (score 1):

How would you deserialize the xml House stream back to a House object on the receiving end?
I'm refering to the solution given in Fischermaen's answer.

On my recieving end I can see a string representation in my Output window by using the following:

```
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT *****

Ok well this solution has worked for me. Might need some tidying up.

Here's a method to deserialize a string:

```
public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        T result;
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Then from my TPC/IP Recieving end I call the method like so:

```
TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();


        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                //blocks until a client sends a message
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                //a socket error has occured
                break;
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                //the client has disconnected from the server
                break;
            }


            //message has successfully been received
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

            House house = DeserializeFromXml<House>(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

            //Send Message Back
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Client - " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }

        tcpClient.Close();
    }
```