# send array with socket C# winforms

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, send

how to send a array with socket like java 'outputstream'?
can u see any demos or example serialization ?
I can send a simple text with socket to my client. But how can I send array, List or Class to my client. I want to send this format
*List array;*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510204/c-sharp-tcpclient-send-serialized-objects-using-separators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `outputstream` can not do what you want either, all it can do is send `byte[]` which is exactly what C#'s socket classes do.

If you want to send complex objects you must use some form of "Serializer" which will let you transform your objects in to a `byte[]` to be sent out.

A easy to use serializer that is built in to .NET is [`XmlSeralizer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), this will produce a string that you can then feed in to a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) which will convert the string to a `byte[]` and write it out on to the socket. The other end would just use the reverse process using a `StreamReader`.

If you do not want to use that intermediate text step I would ***NOT*** recomend using [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) like you see frequently on the internet, it is very "fragil" and having different levels of .NET Windows updates installed on both ends can end up breaking it. Instead I recommend using a 3rd party binary serializer like [Protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

Comment: **thanks** there is json parser and serializer in c#?

Comment: @jjj [Yes there is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) however most people consider the built in library not that great and most people ususally end up using [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), it is very easy to add to your project via [NuGet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/10/16/nuget-is-a-net-framework-release-vehicle.aspx) just select [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) from the [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console)