# multipart message stream handling in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, tcp, persistence

I need to parse a TCP data stream that contains protocol-defined binary-formatted messages that may or may not be multipart. Headers in the message indicate if the message has more than one part (part 1 of 4, etc). I am parsing single-part messages successfully with a message class that decodes the byte data into the class members - this accounts for about 95% of all traffic.

I'm new to c#-dotNet with most of my experience in C++, and the old way of managing this is to have an array of field endpoints that can store a reference to a data structure that I can grow as needed while the message is being rebuilt on the receiving end. I've researched possible methods for a C# equivalent, but they seem to be HTTP oriented and use the file system for temporary storage, but I'm looking for a method for message building in memory. My grasp of C# classes, persistence, garbage collection, etc, are limited to the point that I'm not sure of an approach.

My TCP handler has a callback message handler that parses messages for 'abc' protocol:

```
void processTcpPacket(StateObject tcpControl)
{
    abcMessage abc = new abcMessage();
    abc.parse(tcpControl.buffer,tcpControl.size)
    if(abc.complete)
    {
        do something with this message()
    }else if abc.multipart{
        hold this message somewhere until the next part shows up... ?
    }else{
        discard unparseable message()
    }
}
```

processTcpPacket() is asynchronous, and delivers messages from many endpoints; the headers in each message have full source and destination addresses. This protocol will divide a long message into segments of roughly 200 bytes that are sent to the receiver and reassembled - the largest payload can be up to ~5000 bytes.

In the C++ world, I would create a storage container for multipart messages that has the source address of the sendee, so I can find the right container and keep adding message parts until the message is complete, then process the message and delete the temporary container.  Is there a similar process I can follow with C#?

Comment: Sure, you're looking for a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which allows you store something based on key lookup.

Comment: Maybe you want to see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510978/932418). It uses NewLine char as packet separator and uses json as packet container.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the point, neither of these allows me to create an object to 'remember' the partial data until the next asynchronous callback. This object has to persist outside the callback...

Comment: Right...declare the Dictionary at Class level so it persists across calls and add the the "abc' instance using the source address as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless I'm missing the point, neither of these allows me to create an
>   object to 'remember' the partial data until the next asynchronous
>   callback. This object has to persist outside the callback...

Right...declare the Dictionary at Class level so it persists across calls and add the the "abc' instance using the source address as the key.

Here's some very rough pseudo-code:

```
Dictionary<sourceAddress, abcMessage> msgs = new Dictionary<sourceAddress, abcMessage>();

void processTcpPacket(StateObject tcpControl)
{
    if (msgs.ContainsKey(sourceAddress))
    {
        abcMessage abc = msgs[sourceAddress]; // pull partial from the dictionary
        abc.AddParse(tcpControl.buffer,tcpControl.size); // do you have a way to ADD a message yet?
        if(abc.complete)
        {
            do something with this message()
        }
        // if partial, it's already stored in the dictionary, leave it there
    }
    else
    {
        abcMessage abc = new abcMessage();
        abc.parse(tcpControl.buffer,tcpControl.size)
        if(abc.complete)
        {
            do something with this message()
        }else if abc.multipart{
            msgs.Add(sourceAddress, abc); // hold this message somewhere until the next part shows up... ?              
        }else{
            discard unparseable message()
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what you want to store the "sourceAddress" key type as.  It could be a string form of the IP, or some other way to uniquely identify the source.