# Serialize and Deserialize a packet

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, interface

i m trying to get a bit deeper into sockets applications , and i'm trying to create a server/Client application with **Packets** as a **Serialized Classes** 

Example :

```
[Serializable]
class Msg 
{
    public String Cmd { get; set; }

    public Msg(String M)
    {
        this.Cmd = M;
    }

}
```

I m trying to make it easy to read and **cleaner** using `interfaces`

```
public interface Packet
{
    void Execute();
}
```

Packets :

```
[Serializable]
class Msg : Packet
{
    public String Cmd { get; set; }

    public Msg(String M)
    {
        this.Cmd = M;
    }
    public void Execute()
    {
      Sender.Send(this);
    }
}
```

My question is while Deserializing the Packet is it possible to Deserialize to know the type of the packet for example :

```
   Packet p = (Packet)Data; // data is the packet sent by the Client Desiralized
   var type = p.GetType();
```

then use it like :

```
if (type== Typeof(Packet.Msg))
   {
       // handle data
   }
```

is it possible to get packet type across Packet Interface?

**EDIT :** 
cause i noticed in .NET in System.Type reference there is  GetType Method Return the Type of the Class so i was a was trying to know if it can returns the type of the class (packet)

Something Like :

```
    public void Send<T>(T packet) where T : IPacket
    {
        if (!Connected || packet == null) return;

        lock (_sendBuffers)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    _parentServer.Serializer.Serialize(ms, packet);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Disconnect();
                    return;
                }

                byte[] payload = ms.ToArray();

                _sendBuffers.Enqueue(payload);

                OnClientWrite(packet, payload.LongLength, payload);

                lock (_sendingPacketsLock)
                {
                    if (_sendingPackets) return;

                    _sendingPackets = true;
                }
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Send);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using a text based protocol like xml or json, so that you can easily define the type in it by simple inspection. Maybe something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510978/932418

Comment: my question was about using interfaces its not like i need a solution , i need to understand using it that way

Comment: OK, I am waiting your new questions after you've solved your problem with interfaces which are always problems when serializing/deserializing of objects :)

Comment: I guess my question wasn't too good , i' ll edit it

Comment: cruny, The idea is simple. if share a common assembly between client & server, send an info about the type you serialized and the receiver can control the deserialization process to return the correct type (also assuming that type has a default constructor) then is possible. Otherwise receiving end have to guess.... Now show  your serialization/deserialization code so that we can help you....

Comment: BTW: Don't forget you send *data* (using serialization) to the server not *code*....

Comment: @L.B i found this Method on a project in github something like that i didnt understand fully

Comment: curry, it just simply serializes some object and enqueues it for sending.... Not related with your original question about interfaces.... I think you should read some more docs because you don't know what is going on under the hood :( My thinking on problems like this is: *All you can send from client to server is just a sequence of bytes... So since there isn't a magic here, how can i recreate the original class at receiver end* ....

Comment: @L.B Yes sir thanks ! , M trying not to be so confused but , lets say we have some packets Server Packets (Msg, Order,Dosomework) those are classes that inherite from the interface Packet , i want to send for example Message Packet , i seralize it and send it in the Client side i have to check what the received packet type is

Comment: Please create a [*create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise it is too broad to answer here. See also http://sscce.org/