# Read data in separed blocks from a socket server c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, bytebuffer

I have this code:

```
        void Start(Socket ServerSocket)
    {

       var socketConnected = ServerSocket.Accept();
        var state = new State()
        {
            socket = socketConnected,
            buffer = new byte[2048]              
        };

        ServerSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallBack, state);

    }

    void ReadCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var state = (State)result.AsyncState;

       int readData = state.socket.EndReceive(result);

        if(readData > 0)
        {
            //Do Work
        }
        state.socket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallBack, state);
    }
```

It works perfectly, receiving data from a client.
The problem is that when the client sends two data asynchronous requests. The
server receives data all together in the same array.
I would like know if there is another way of doing it so that the data is separated.

Comment: You probably want to `Flush()` the sender.

Comment: yes, but i do not have that method.

Comment: `i would like know if exists any way to do it ?` No there isn't a method that assures this. (Not even you had a method lile `Flush`)  You have to implement a custom protocol... (Sending a packet length before your data or using a separator char etc.)

Comment: i only have "Send" and if the server takes a delay and the client send tow message , server receives one message all bytes together in the same array

Comment: *Goto* previous comment...

Comment: the problemm is that client sends a custom objet serialized

Comment: @Elias And? You can send its length first and then the actual data.. BTW: see also  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21510978/932418

Comment: OK, thanks, its a good idea i will take 5 first bytes to send length to read

Comment: @Elias 5 bytes can address  ~1TB... Don't you think 4-byte (which is an int/uint) enough?

Comment: yes, you're razon

Comment: @Elias Hope it is a good thing...