# TCP Client Connection Time out

Tags: c#, windows, tcp, tcpclient

So I made a chat program with connections codes like these

Client

[image: Client code]

Server

[image: Server code]

Now it works perfectly fine with LAN

[image: Lan connection works]

But for the love of god I can't figure out why WAN is not working

[image: WAN is not working]

Now I know that everyone at this point is blaming the firewall or port forwarding but ! I've done all that correctly and here's the proof ! When I use a port check tool to check if the server is up the server crashes cause I didn't place a try catch block to handle unknown requests yet !

[image]

And if your thinking maybe it's the DNS no it is not I entered the host address there and it still connects to the server ! Plus I checked with the autos the address it's trying to connect is indeed my IP !
How weird is that !!! I have been looking at my code for hours now... please help

Comment: Hm,  I could help you to figure it out via a teamviewer meeting, If you want add me Nickname : Zerray

Comment: Please post actual code. SO has a feature to display code.

Comment: Zerray I can't find you mate... Care to add me instead ? FrostByte

Answer (score 2):

You don't accept any connection other than from `192.168.1.100`. Create your TCPListener with `IPAddress.Any` not with `serverAddress`.

Comment: I just changed the code to IPAddress.Any, it had no effect on the connection.

Comment: On top of which now even the open port check tool is unable to connect to the server ! 192.168.1.100 is a static IP of my machine on my network !

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed see an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510204/c-sharp-tcpclient-send-serialized-objects-using-separators

Comment: IPAddress.Any would be useful if I was hosting my server on LAN but I am hosting my server on WAN meaning I have to listen to any incoming connections to my machines IPAddress I've done this before and I know for a fact that it should be 192.168.1.100 and not IPAddress.Any plus I tested ir with IPAddress.Any but it did not work ! On top even the Open port checker couldn't connect any longer !!!

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed  `IPAddress.Any would be useful if I was hosting my server on LAN but....` Seem you don't understand the concept. http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/tcpclient-connects-localhost-192-168-1-localhostip-454849.html

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed : The IP that you give to the `TcpListener` is the IP that it will accept connections from. Specifying `192.168.1.100` will make it allow connections from _**THAT LAN IP ONLY**_ (WAN won't work), meaning only one computer (located in LAN) will ever be able to connect to it. `IPAddress.Any` is what you must use because it allows connections from _**any**_ IP address (LAN or otherwise).

Comment: But I tried that, if anything it made things worse !

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed : Then you have another problem. Perhaps the computer's firewall? Or the use of a proxy? -- I can assure you though that what I said is the case: You need `IPAddress.Any` (equivalent to `0.0.0.0`) to allow connections from _**any**_ IP, whether it is internal or external.

Comment: @ShaamilAhmed : It could also be related to a badly configured network (not implying yours is, but it's worth looking over the router settings).